# How to distribute file storage to a different filesystem with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

First of: I just got started using CLIs to manage a whole server, sorry if this question is stupid, but I couldn't find any solution to this.

I ran into a problem with `apt-get -f install`, because my disk is full. `df -h` returns:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01   37G  8.1G   28G  23% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                   483M   12K  483M   1% /dev
tmpfs                   99M  592K   99M   1% /run
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   494M     0  494M   0% /run/shm
none                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1              464M  459M     0 100% /boot
```

As you can see, my filesystem `/boot` is full. How could I go on about "giving" boot some space from `/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01`? I am pretty stuck. Appreciate any help on this

Comment: You can try running: `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Can't run it, because then it says "run apt-get -f install" :(((

Comment: In general, you could move some data to another mountpoint and symlink it back. Since it is /boot (and has to be loaded by the bootloader) it might render your system unbootable, though (General, I don't think there is any way (unless you have space directly after /boot on your drive) to online resize /boot.

Comment: What is on your /boot? If it is a lot of older kernels, move a few of them (other than the latest and the currently booted one) away, finish the installation, then properly uninstall old kernels you do not need any longer. In general, a few 100 MB ought to be enough for /boot.

Comment: or in case you really want to grow /boot, add `lsblk` output to your post, so we see the partition layout.

Comment: `/boot` generally does not use LVM, so you would need to expand the partition manually (using parted, gparted, etc) but that requires sequential blocks free after the /boot partition, which generally doesn't happen. (People don't usually intentionally leave space between partitions when systems are built). This will take some major work to do, but decide up front if it would be faster to reload the whole system, giving /boot much more space the 2nd time around.

Comment: @mihi thank you for the insight! I begin to understand a little more.

Comment: @TimS. thank you, too. I guess it makes sense in the end, I just realised, what /boot is for. I thought it's full because I installed packages over gem......... My bad. Quite confusing at first, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

> This command removes packages that were installed by other packages
>   and are no longer needed.

I assume you have unused kernel images making boot partition full. And if you can't run the above command then you will need to clean /boot partition manually. First you can use the following command to find out the installed kernel:

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
```

The other kernel versions (other than that listed above) can be removed manually like this:

```
sudo  rm /boot/*-unused-kernel-version*
```

**Always be very carefull when using `rm -rf`as root and delete only the unused kernels.**

When you have some space free in /boot then run again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You may find this post very usefull:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition

Comment: Hello, thank you really much for the answer. I checked your answer and the answer on askubuntu, but I think I am doing something wrong. So I tried to delete the oldest version like this: sudo rm -rf /boot/*-3.13.0-24.47, but it is still there. Also tried without the dash, or do I have to delete "abi-3.13.0-24-generic" each on it's own?

Comment: @FrederikWitte, you are welcome. yes, you can write the full filename. Do like this, first `cd /boot`, and then `ls -al` this will list all files. then you can use, `rm filename`.

Comment: @FrederikWitte, the `*` is used to match multiple similar file names in one command.